# Inserting data into C# Datasets

Tags: c#, .net, strongly-typed-dataset

I am using C#.Net application in which i created a dataset.Now i want to create a method in which i will enter a record in one table which will return a value ie primary key.Now by using that primary key i have to insert records in 5 tables and i have to use that primary key as a foreign key for this 5 tables using dataset.

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: @Brisbe42: I fear your question is too short for Apy.

Comment: When asking questions, think of "title" as subject and the box below for detailed description. Think of it as question in form of an email.

Answer (score 1):

> **You need to tell your parent table's table-adapter to refresh the
>   data-table after update operation.
>   This is how you can do that.**

1. Open the properties of **ParentTableAdapter -> Default Select Query -> Advnaced options**. and Check the option of **Refresh the data table**. Save the adapter now. Now when you call update on table-adapter, the **data-table will be updated [refreshed] after the update operation** and will reflect the latest values from database table. **if the primary-key or any coloumn is set to auto-increment, the data-table will have those latest value post recent update.**
2. Now you can Call the update as ParentTableAdapterObj.Update(ds.dataTable);
3. **Read latest values from the ParentDataTable(ds.dataTable) coloumns and assign respective values into the child table before update**. This will work exactly the way you want.

[alt text http://ruchitsurati.net/files/tds1.png](http://ruchitsurati.net/files/tds1.png)

Comment: This is good advice if you're using SQL-server. It won't work [if you are using an access db though](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/18a5409d-c61c-413b-b09d-bfb0d800999d/), the checkbox will be greyed out. (actually anything that uses OLEDB)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried temporary key linkage until the DB generates the final key? Works great for me.