# Get id when inserting new row using TableAdapter.Update on a file based database

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-ce, jet

I have a database table with one field, called ID, being an auto increment integer.
Using a TableAdapter I can read and modify existing rows as well as create new ones.

However if I try to modify a newly inserted row I get an DBConcurrencyException:

```
 OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Shift.mdb;Persist Security Info=True");
 ShiftDataSetTableAdapters.ShiftTableAdapter shiftTA = new ShiftDataSetTableAdapters.ShiftTableAdapter();
 shiftTA.Connection = conn;

 ShiftDataSet.ShiftDataTable table = new ShiftDataSet.ShiftDataTable();
 ShiftDataSet.ShiftRow row = table.NewShiftRow();
 row.Name = "life";
 table.Rows.Add(row);
 shiftTA.Update(row); // row.ID == -1
 row.Name = "answer"; // <-- all fine up to here
 shiftTA.Update(row); // DBConcurrencyException: 0 rows affected
```

*Separate question, is there any static type of the NewShiftRow() method I can use so that I don't have to create table everytime I want to insert a new row.*

I guess the problem in the code comes from row.ID that is still -1 after the first Update() call. The Insert is successful and in the database the row has a valid value of ID.

How can I get that ID so that I can continue with the second Update call?

**Update:**

IT looks like this could have been done automatically using [this setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425022/inserting-data-into-c-datasets).
However according to the answer on [msdn social](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/18a5409d-c61c-413b-b09d-bfb0d800999d/), OLEDB drivers do not support this feature.

Not sure where to go from here, use something else than oledb?

**Update:**

Tried SQLCompact but discovered that it had the same [limitation](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/DotNet/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.adonet/2008-05/msg00169.html), it does not support multiple statements.

Final question: is there any simple(single file based) database that would allow you to get the values of a inserted row.

Comment: hook the RowUpdated event and assign ID from there http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815629

Comment: regarding your final question (single file based database), Sqlite perfectly fits the bill.  see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599230/anyway-see-why-i-get-this-concurrency-violation-in-these-few-lines-of-code/1604547#1604547

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815629 , the sample code is in VB.NET though.

Or if multiline query is accepted in MS Access and it has built-in function/variable for retrieving the last id, use this (the database is SQLite though): [anyway see why I get this "Concurrency Violation" in these few lines of code??? Concurrency violation: the UpdateCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599230/anyway-see-why-i-get-this-concurrency-violation-in-these-few-lines-of-code/1604547#1604547) , try to google for the function

**[EDIT: Works on my Machine, I don't have SQL Server Compact, but I didn't use multi-statement]**

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();


    var c = Connect();

    var da = new SqlDataAdapter("select emp_id, emp_firstname, emp_lastname from emp where 1 = 0", c);



    var b = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);

    var getIdentity = new SqlCommand("SELECT CAST(@@IDENTITY AS INT)", c);

    da.InsertCommand = b.GetInsertCommand();
    da.UpdateCommand = b.GetUpdateCommand();
    da.DeleteCommand = b.GetDeleteCommand();
    da.RowUpdated += (xsender, xe) =>
    {
        if (xe.Status == UpdateStatus.Continue && xe.StatementType == StatementType.Insert)
        {
            xe.Row["emp_id"] = (int)getIdentity.ExecuteScalar();
        }
    };


    var dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);

    var nr = dt.NewRow();
    nr["emp_firstname"] = "john";
    nr["emp_lastname"] = "lennon";


    var nrx = dt.NewRow();
    nrx["emp_firstname"] = "paul";
    nrx["emp_lastname"] = "mccartney";


    dt.Rows.Add(nr);
    dt.Rows.Add(nrx);

    da.Update(dt);

    dt.AcceptChanges();


    nrx["emp_lastname"] = "simon";
    da.Update(dt);

    nr["emp_lastname"] = "valjean";
    da.Update(dt);

}



SqlConnection Connect()
{
    return new SqlConnection(@"data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Test;uid=sa;pwd=hey");
}
```

Comment: I like the idea but I have not yet had time to look into this, but I will. 

I assume this will work with my current custom DataSet/Table/Rows.

Answer (score -1):

Why not select the MAX(RowId), as your RowId should increment for each INSERT? Is this possible for you?

As for your final answer, [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) might be the perfect tool for you. I hope so! And it has its own .NET Data Provider, so no need for OLEDB or ODBC providers.

Comment: I am careful with looking for the max since another application could have inserted a new record in between.
In my specific case the data was known to be unique so a full search on all column values solved the problem so far.

Comment: You're right, Phq, selecting the Max(Id) isn't a really neat solution, and it mostly gets the job done. However, I didn't know about @@IDENTITY outside of SQL Server as stated in Micheal Buen's answer. That is THE solution! =)